# Form of equations, minus inside and outside bracket

Tags: equation-solving

I have output :

```
-((Ctot (-1 + E^((-kb - kf) t)) kb)/(kb + kf))
```

how can I change to form

```
((Ctot (1 - E^((-kb - kf) t)) kb)/(kb + kf))
```

so forcing the minus into the bracket.

Comment: The first form has a smaller `LeafCount`, so for MMA it's simpler and hence it will choose this form.

Answer (score 3):

A substitution involving `HoldForm` can give the *appearance* that you request

```
expr = -((Ctot (-1 + E^((-kb - kf) t)) kb)/(kb + kf));
expr /. -1 + u_ :> -HoldForm[1 - u]
```

Onward manipulation may require the use of `ReleaseHold`.

I frequently find this approach useful.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  I required to implement ReleaseHold.as you mentioned!  :-)